# I am getting an error : syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors

Tags: perl, scripting

The perl script is written to send the data .
and it is throwing the exception as seen :

> syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF Execution of -e aborted due to
>   compilation errors.

Code :

```
patln=`awk -v dat="$dt" '$0 ~ dat {print NR}' *path of the file where the logs are present*| head -1` 

STATUS=$( perl -ne "print if $. >= $patln" *path of the file where the logs are present* | grep TABLE
```

Comment: The shown code has an unbalanced parenthesis, and the `*path of the file where the logs are present*` isn't really there, is it? Post the real code.

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double quotes around your perl code?

Comment: I tried using single quotes ..no help .

Comment: yes the log files exist.

Comment: How do you compute the variable `$pathln` ? Do you still get syntax error if you replace the Perl script with `perl -ne "print" ... ` ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to generate Perl code!

```sh
# Use an env var.
export patln
perl -ne'print if $. >= $ENV{patln} && /TABLE/' -- "$LOG"
```

or

```sh
# Use an env var (expected to one process only).
patln="$patln" perl -ne'print if $. >= $ENV{patln} && /TABLE/' -- "$LOG"
```

or

```sh
# Use arguments (e.g. using -s)
perl -sne'print if $. >= $patln && /TABLE/' -- -patln="$patln" -- "$LOG"
```

or

```sh
# Perl not even needed here.
tail -n +"$patln"  -- "$LOG" | grep TABLE
```